# scroll to the div

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have this test here, http://uwptestsite.uwpistol.net/work.html loads of images, each showing and hiding divs

When i click on an image near the bottom of my screen, how do i get the page to scroll enough so the revealed div is visible?

I've tried scroll to plug-in, I've tried

```
$(document.body).animate({scrollTop: $('#slide13').offset().top}, 2000);
```

I'm pretty stumped, any of the tests I've tried to implement from previous questions here, won't work, with no errors or anything.

Anyone any ideas? or suggestions? I hope I'm making sense
Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

demos: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: these are two VERY solid plugins - highly recommended.

Comment: This is the one I've tried that I can't get to work... I've added $('.content').scrollTo($("#slide13")); in a callback after the div I want is revealed..

Comment: Do I want localScroll plugin?

Comment: `$.scrollTo($("#slide13"), 1000)`

Comment: works in Chrome and Safari. Show your code or digg for an error